# How to deploy by using git?

Tags: git, deployment

I'm a single developer and I have dev machine and prod machine. I'm developing in master branch. When I need to push on prod I need to exclude some files. I can't add them in .gitignore because it make them untracked.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly but you can't (shouldn't) use Git to deploy an application.

Git is a distributed source control system, not a deployment system.

If you are looking for deployment tools I'd recommend checking out (no pun intended) the following:

- [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) - easy to learn/use but not very powerful (no MSI)
- [NSIS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nsis/) - The Nullsoft Scriptable Instal System, also pretty easy to learn (no MSI)
- [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) - really powerful but pretty steep learning curve
- [InstallAware](http://www.installaware.com/) - commercial software but had free limited version
- [InstallShield](http://www.installshield.com/) - commercial software, pretty powerful, GUI based

Comment: Can you advise some deploy tools?

Answer (score 1):

git update-index --assume-unchanged path/

From [git-update-index](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html) man page:

> When these flags are specified, the object names recorded for the paths are not updated. Instead, these options set and unset the "assume unchanged" bit for the paths. When the "assume unchanged" bit is on, git stops checking the working tree files for possible modifications, so you need to manually unset the bit to tell git when you change the working tree file. This is sometimes helpful when working with a big project on a filesystem that has very slow lstat(2) system call (e.g. cifs).
>
> This option can be also used as a coarse file-level mechanism to ignore uncommitted changes in tracked files (akin to what .gitignore does for untracked files). Git will fail (gracefully) in case it needs to modify this file in the index e.g. when merging in a commit; thus, in case the assumed-untracked file is changed upstream, you will need to handle the situation manually.

Answer (score 1):

Git is not a deployment tool, but you can easily adopt it to work as follows:

- when you push to the remote, its working directory will be updated.

Thus with a push you can update the files on the server.

Here is the procedure:

Create two repositories: `repoDev` (here you work), `repoDeploy` (this is the repo on your server)

```
$ git init repoDev
//add some commits to your repoDev

$ git init repoDeploy
```

Inside `repoDeploy` execute:

```
//in repoDeploy
$ git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore
$ git config core.worktree ../
```

The above commands define, that when you push to `repoDeploy`,
its working directory will be updated with your push.

Configure `repoDev`:

```
//in repoDev
$ git remote add deploy URL-of-repoDeploy
```

Push:

```
//in repoDev
//commit some changes
$ git push deploy master
```

The working directory of `repoDeploy` should be updated.

Using different branches for your `prod` and `dev` environments should solve the problem.

Work with your `dev` version in `dev` branch, and your `prod` version should go to `prod` branch.

If you want to push `dev` branch to the prod server execute:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge dev
$ git push deploy master
```

Maybe you can also set the default branch on `repoDeploy`, in a way that:

```
git push deploy prod
```

will checkout the files in the working directory using `prod` branch. But I didn't test it.